# Why deliberately mismatch impedances in RF?

Tags: amplifier, rf, bandwidth, impedance-matching

My professor wants me to design a cascaded RF amplifier, with mismatched stages. The reasoning is to increase bandwidth. Is this correct? If so, can anyone elaborate on the theory why mismatching increases bandwidth?

Comment: Have you tried asking him?

Comment: Have you tried asking google? Maybe look it up and then ask if you have trouble understanding something. Much easier than asking one of us to waste time writing a wikipedia article for you.

Comment: @LeonHeller The professor doesn't explain because it is beyond the scope of the course.

Comment: @I.Wolfe Do you know where to start? I'm posting here because google results are all very advanced, such as technical journals. Even the wikipedia article does not really elaborate the relationship between bandwidth and matching.

Comment: If it's beyond the scope of the course that's exactly why he should explain. Are you sure he is referring to impedance, not bandwidth?

Comment: I don't know why this is being down voted so badly. It is, it seems to me, a question worth an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Design strategies do exist that involve intentionally mismatching stages. In my opinion, there are better ways to increase bandwidth, but mismatching is one method.

Say you're designing a 2-stage amp at 10ghz. Matching both stages at 10ghz might produce an amp with 0.5ghz skirts, resulting in gain from 9.5-10.5ghz, or 1ghz of bandwidth.

Now let's mismatch the two stages. Match one at 9.5ghz and one at 10.5ghz. Assume each stage still has 0.5ghz skirts. The overall amp will now have gain from 9.0-11ghz, or 2ghz of bandwidth.

The key here is, each stage has a gain curve that looks something like a bell curve. If two bell curves are offset, then added together, the result is a wider bell curve with a lower maximum.